# GitHub pages only showing ReadMe file in React App?

Tags: reactjs, github

I have found so many similar cases of this on here, but I honestly am so confused on what to do. I've been trying to work this our for hours now, but whatever I try isn't working. Anyone know the best thing to do please? I recognize its an issue with my index.html, but I cant figure it out.
code:
https://github.com/iloloizu/portfolio
website:
https://iloloizu.github.io/portfolio/

Please help

Answer (score 0):

if you're all set precisely by the official tutorials ([react-gh-pages](https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages) & [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages)), and yet you can't see your project running, probably you have to go to your GitHub repository `setting` > `pages`, and change the source branch to `gh-pages`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Create React App:

1. Make sure you have

> "scripts": {
> "build": "react-scripts build"
> }

in your package.json file.

2. Create a gh-pages branch.
3. On the gh-pages branch, run:

> npm run build

4. Move all the content in the build folder out into the root folder.
5. Commit your changes to the gh-pages branch and

> git push origin gh-pages

6. In your GitHub repository settings, go to the "GitHub Pages" section, select the source branch to be "gh-pages" and the folder to be "root", and save.

Then the deployed website should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please use gh-pages as production dependacy instead of --save-dev , this tric worked for after waisting 1 hour